# len method undefined

Tags: go

I've been reading the [golang-book]: http://www.golang-book.com and completing the excercises as I go along.  In Chapter 6, there is an exercise that must find the smallest element in an unsorted list[x].

I have the following code but somehow I don't know why the method length (len) gives me an error on **line 14: x.len undefined (type []int has no field or method len)**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }

    small := x[0]
    for i := 1; i < x.len(); i++ {
        if x[i] < small {
            fmt.Println(x[i])
        }
    }
}
```

The logic I used was Googled so perhaps there is no len method on arrays?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"The logic I used was Googled..."* I don't know what that means, but no, there's no `len()` method on Arrays. I would imagine the book describes how to properly get the length of an Array.

Comment: ...yep, quick look through [chapter 6](http://www.golang-book.com/6) answers your question.

Comment: As @Daniel mentioned, length is not a method of slice, but rather built in as global function, understood.  But, why does the compiler give me six elements (37 34 27 19 9 17) and not the unique value of 9 ? (9 being smallest int found in x)

Comment: Because you asked it to: `fmt.Println(x[i])`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays and slices do not have a len() method.  The len() function is a language built-in.

So your code

```
for i := 1; i < x.len(); i++ {
```

Should be

```
for i := 1; i < len(x); i++ {
```

Here is a working version in [the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/hVetB2_acU).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    x := []int{
        48,96,86,68,
        57,82,63,70,
        37,34,83,27,
        19,97, 9,17,
    }   

    small := x[0]
    for i := 1; i < len(x); i++ {
        if x[i] < small { 
        fmt.Println(x[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have branched your code with a small change to avoid evaluating `len(x)` on every loop: http://play.golang.org/p/QS-Ov9PeyY

Comment: @Tom; There is no point in doing that. It doesn't cost anything to evaluate len(x).

Comment: @peterSO: No cost? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @the system: Yes. A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array segment, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment). The len built-in function obtains the length of the segment from the descriptor.

Comment: @peterSO: So when you say it doesn't cost anything, you mean it doesn't need to calculate the length, but it does need to read the length. In other words, it doesn't perform the `len()` once, and then automatically cache the result.

Comment: @the system: The `len` built-in function does not calculate the length of a slice. When the compiler encounters the `len` built-in function for a slice it generates the machine code to load the length of the segment from the slice descriptor into a register, unless it knows that the length is already in a register.

Comment: @thesystem No, it doesn't caches len, but calculating len (there is no calculation) is O(1).

Answer (score 4):

`len()` isn't a method of a slice. It's a global function. You want to say `len(x)`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{
        48, 96, 86, 68,
        57, 82, 63, 70,
        37, 34, 83, 27,
        19, 97, 9, 17,
    }

    small := x[0]
    for i := 1; i < len(x); i++ {
        if x[i] < small {
            fmt.Println(x[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, array- and slice-types **can** have a `len()` method, like this:

http://play.golang.org/p/CkU4LJZgUb

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SliceType []int

func (s SliceType) len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func main() {
    s := SliceType{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    for i := 0; i < s.len(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(s[i])
    }
}
```

The code you found is probably an implementation of [`container/list`](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/#List.Len) or [`container/ring`](http://golang.org/pkg/container/ring/#Ring.Len), both of which specify a `Len()` method.

Primitive slices and arrays, though, don't have **any** methods attached to them and you must use the built-in function `len()`.